# Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server - error when opening service-based database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

First of all, I know this has been asked several times, but I have been searching the solution for a while and I couldn't find it, that's why I'm opening this.

I'm trying to open a service based database in Visual Studio 2010 which was sent to me in a C# project. I recently updated to SQL Server 2012.

[image: Error message idalog]

In other threads the common solution was to delete the `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Data` folder, but it did not help for me.

I tried a few other things, but I might not have done it right, so I guess trying it again, if someone suggests that, would not be a bad idea.

Connection string I'm using:

```
<add name="Database1Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model‌​1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DBName;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

**UPDATE**

With setting the user instance to false i can open the database now. However, when running the project i get the following error:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The *user instance* feature is **only** available in the **Express** edition, and in SQL Server 2012, it's been replaced by the `LocalDB` functionality

Comment: Can you please show ConnectionString you using? I assume you need to change connectonstring after updating to SQL Server 2012

Comment: Could you please tell me where i can find the ConnectionString I'm using?

Comment: Try to search inside App.Config file inside your C# Project dir

Comment: <add name="Database1Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DBName;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

Comment: This is the full line. sorry for just copying it, but i didn't want to copy out the wrong part of it.

Comment: Try to completely remove `User Instance=False;` block from the connectionString attribute.

Comment: Removed, but still no good :/